# Check if image has alpha channel

Tags: image-processing, opacity

How can I check if an `Image` has an alpha channel?

---

"What have you tried?"

- `AlphaChannel` and `ColorSeparate[..., "A"]` return a result even if the image had no explicit alpha channel.
- We could check the number of results from `ColorSeparate` or `ImageChannels`, but that also depends on `ColorSpace`, which may also be a `ColorProfileData` object (for which it isn't clear how to determine the number of expected channels).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just discovered this command (in the Properties and Relations sections of the `AlphaChannel` command)

```
ImageMeasurements[img, "Transparency"]
```

It returns `True` if there is an alpha channel and `False` otherwise.

Comment: It's a weird place to put this functionality, isn't it?  It relies on ``Image`ImageInformation`` which is a much more natural name for something like this. "Measurement" implies work/computation.  Of course *it was* in the `AlphaChannel` documentation, so this is the kind of question that usually gets closed as "easily (?) found in the documentation".

Comment: I was surprised at the whole ImageMeasurements command. It seems like an odd complement to ComponentMeasurements (which also takes images as input).

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
RemoveAlphaChannel[img] == img
```

If img has no alpha channel, this returns True, but returns False if img has an alpha channel.

```
SetAlphaChannel[img] == img
```

seems to work too, but with the reverse logic.

Comment: This works. What I don't love about it is that the performance depends on the image size.  There should be a constant time way.

Answer (score 4):

As of V12, [`Information`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html#1717645549) can return this:

[image]

```
Information[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Transparency"]
```

> ```
> False
> ```