# Why is the color changed after applying ImageData?

Tags: image-processing, color, image

I have an image `square.png` as below:-

[image]

I imported the image as `ImageSquare`, and then applied `ImageData` to the image. When I applied `Image` to convert the image back, the color is changed:-

```
ImageSquare = Import@StringJoin[NotebookDirectory[], "square.png"]
ImageSquare2 = Image@ImageData@ImageSquare
```

[image]

Why is that? In fact if I checked the value of the images, I still got `True`:

```
(ImageData@ImageSquare2) == (ImageData@ImageSquare)
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the `ColorSpace` manually:

```
ImageSquare2 = Image[ImageData@ImageSquare, ColorSpace -> "RGB"]
```

Or take it from the original image:

```
colorSpace = Options@ImageSquare
ImageSquare2 = Image[ImageData@ImageSquare, colorSpace]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The original approach yield:

```
Options@(Image@ImageData@ImageSquare)
(* {ColorSpace -> Automatic, Interleaving -> True} *)
```

Which is wrong and uses the following rule from [`Image`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.html):

> ```
> {c1,c2,c3,…}  channel values rendered by equally spaced hues
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This happens because this PNG file has three colour channels (RGB) and an additional alpha channel (transparency).

When applying `ImageData` (or `ColorSeparate`) blindly, we simply get four channels as the result. But the information on how to interpret these (i.e. RGB + alpha) is lost.  Re-combining them gives a generic 4-channel image, not an RGB one (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157515/12) one how it's displayed).

I suggest removing the alpha channel before using `ImageData`: [`RemoveAlphaChannel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveAlphaChannel.html).

Otherwise, use `ColorSpace -> "RGB"` with `Image` or the second argument of [`ColorCombine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorCombine.html) when recombining the channels. The fourth channel will be interpreted as an alpha channel in this case.

You can check if an image has an alpha channel like this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157458/12

Comment: Thanks. I tried RemoveAlphaChannel as you suggested and it really works. But I don't understand why it matters. I noticed that `MinMax@(ImageData@ImageSquare)[[All, All, 4]]` is just `{1,1}`. Besides, why is the color-at-the-left of `ImageSquare` and `ImageSquare2` are still the same? I also tried to change the alpha-value of `ImageSquare`, but that doesn't allow me to reconstruct an image that looks like `ImageSquare2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageSquare2 = Image[ImageData@ImageSquare, Options@ImageSquare]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]